# Cannot Create Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse, image, android-virtual-device

When I attempt to create a new adv, I get the following error message:

```
Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.
```

I know that many people receive this error when the image is not installed on the sdk, but I am positive mine is.

I am currently working on a linux os (Ubuntu 11.04) and everything works perfectly.

I think I might have something in the wrong directory?

In my /opt dir I have the android sdk folder with the Android 4.0 image, and also the eclipse folder I am working in.

Is there a location that I need to copy the image file to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to eclipse->Window->Android Sdk Manager. If you are using android 4.0(API 14) you have to install also ARM eabi v7  System image. Have a try

For reference here is my config.ini in case you want to replace yours:

```
hw.lcd.density=240 
sdcard.size=512M 
skin.name=WVGA800 
skin.path=platforms\android-14\skins\WVGA800 
hw.cpu.arch=arm 
abi.type=armeabi-v7a 
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8 
vm.heapSize=72 
snapshot.present=false 
hw.ramSize=512 
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-14\armeabi-v7a\
```